# optimizing a javascript file with r.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, r.js

I use 3rd party libraries which looks like the following

```
(function ($) {

....

})(jQuery);
```

I have entries for this js in my config.js

```
paths : {
'someLibrary' : 'path/to/someLibrary',
},

shim : {
'someLibrary' : { deps: ['jquery'] }
}
```

It works fine without r.js optimizer, but once I run the optimizer,
I get error, because of the `jQuery is not defined` in the library code.

How do I resolve this?

**edit**

My r.js build file has mainConfigFile set.

Answer (score -1):

you may need to add jquery in the path also like

```
paths : {
'someLibrary' : 'path/to/someLibrary',
jquery : 'path/to/jquery'
},

shim : {
'someLibrary' : { deps: ['jquery'] }
}
```